# Mouse scrolling by 'page'

Tags: mouse, macos

How can I configure OS X Mountain Lion to scroll one 'page' at a time?

OS X's Scrolling Speed in Mouse preferences doesn't have the effect of what I'm looking for.

The default/current behavour is that the first few wheel scrolls is one 'line' at a time. Only when you've scrolled a few wheel clicks in quick sequence does it start to scroll in larger chunks.

I have a Logitech MX 510 mouse. The Logitech control panel has no options here either.

Are there any Mountain Lion tweaks I can make or is there any FREE software to help?

Answer (score 1):

[USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) can do that but it's not free.

[image]

You could also add a rule like this to [KeyRemap4MacBook's private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). The behavior when scrolling multiple ticks was a bit weird on the mouse I tested with; it only scrolled a full page about once every 0.5 seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Test</name>
        <appendix/>
        <identifier>94D0530F-70BA-4DA9-BD45-C223A689A807</identifier>
        <autogen>--ScrollWheelToKey-- ScrollWheel::UP, KeyCode::PAGEUP</autogen>
        <autogen>--ScrollWheelToKey-- ScrollWheel::DOWN, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

You can also increase the scrolling speed with `defaults write -g NSScrollWheelMultiplier -float 200`.